# NullPointerException from getCurrentSession

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hsqldb

I am getting NullPointerException from a simple getCurrentSession() call within a @Transactional annotation method. This is the stacktrace. I am not able to figure out why the cacheProvider is null when I have not even configured any caches.

Has anyone run into similar issues? I searched the forum but most of the questions were never answered.

Hibernate: 3.3

HypersonicSQL: 2.2

This is a single threaded Junit test.

SessionFactory Configuration

```
  <bean id="SessionFactoryAbstractParent" abstract="true">
    <property name="mappingResources">Skipped</property>

    <datasource configuration skipped ... />

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <value>
        hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect
        hibernate.show_sql=true
        hibernate.format_sql=true
        hibernate.max_fetch_depth=1
        hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
        hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
        hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50
        hibernate.order_inserts=true
        hibernate.order_updates=true
        hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
        hibernate.connection.oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout=300000
      </value>
    </property>
  </bean>


  <bean id="SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean" parent="SessionFactoryAbstractParent">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <value>
        hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
        hibernate.show_sql=false
        hibernate.format_sql=true
        hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
        hibernate.max_fetch_depth=1
    hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider
      </value>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge.nextTimestamp(RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge.java:85)
>           at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:526)
>           at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:535)
>           at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.doGetSession(SessionFactoryUtils.java:323)
>           at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.doGetSession(SessionFactoryUtils.java:258)
>           at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:60)
>           at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:574)

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but it seems to me it makes perfect sense that the cacheProvider is null if you haven't configured any caches.

Comment: You will need to post your XML config at least to let us help you. Without your config, we can only guess at the root of the problem. I suspect its because @Transactional is only really used with Hibernate 4. If you are using Hibernate 3, then you are expected to manage the opening, committing and closing of your sessions yourself.

Comment: Added configuration for hibernate. I will try to replace the cacheProvider with newer version and see if that changes anything.